# Automate uploading of videos to YouTube

Tags: youtube, backup, automation

Is there a way to automate uploading of videos straight to YouTube?

I would like to keep lots of home made videos. Of course, they are subject to being lost, or somebody could steal the the computer, or water or fire could destroy them.

Secondly, I have to plug in my hard drive every time I want to watch something, which I find slow and cumbersome.

I was thinking that perhaps I could upload the videos to YouTube with the privacy set to invite-only and then delete the video from the hard drive automatically. Could this be done?

Comment: When the video is uploaded it asks you for information about to to publish it. On that page (which you get to later by finding My Videos and click edit) you can set the name, thumbnail etc and scroll down for Broadcasting and Sharing Options where Private (only people you choose can view) is an option. Also the same for Vimeo.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to implement the YouTube API. The documentation for file uploading can be seen [here](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading.html#Direct_uploading).

Comment: sinni800, I'm having a hard time what to make of the content in your link, it's hard to follow and complicated. Could you upload a YouTube video with screenshots of how to do it?

Comment: He is basically telling you to use the API and code it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with youtube api

For c# my code =

```
    YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",  "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

    Video newVideo = new Video();

    newVideo.Title = srTitle;
    newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Games", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
    newVideo.Keywords = srKeywords;

    newVideo.Description = srDescription;

    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;

    newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(srWhichVideo, "video/wmv");

    ((GDataRequestFactory)request.Service.RequestFactory).Timeout = 9999999;


    Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
    string srVideoUrl = createdVideo.WatchPage.AbsoluteUri.ToString().Replace("&feature=youtube_gdata_player", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [firepype.com](http://firepype.com), it allows you to just drag and drop videos and they post to youtube, Vimeo.